# parsley remote isvalid return null

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

HTML

```
<input data-parsley-trigger="focusout"
       data-parsley-remote="/MailValidation"
       data-parsley-remote-message="error"
       placeholder="mail@mail.com"
       type="email"
       name="Mail"
       id="Mail"
       required
       value="@Model.Mail"
       class="form-control" />
```

JS

```
var p = $("form").parsley();
$('#SaveButton').click(function () {
    p.validate();
    if (p.isValid()) {
        this.form.submit();
    }
});
```

Parsley is not valid. 
 
`p.isValid()` returns null

I was not able to get it to work. Also, I could not find any examples of `whenValidate` on the internet. The resources I have found are very inadequate. Could you please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
var p = $("form").parsley();    
$('#SaveButton').click(function () {
 p.whenValidate().done(function() {
   $("form").submit();
 });
});
```